# How to handle two mouses events

Tags: c#, .net, mono, mouseevent

is there any way, using c# .NET/Mono 2.10 to handle the events sent by two mouses connected to the same computer?

I only want to know when the X's and the Y's of each mouse has changed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you referring to a touch interface?

Comment: Might be worth being bit more specific about the platform because any solution will probably rely on system (API) calls.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout [Windows MultiPoint Mouse SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/multipoint/mouse-sdk/)

Comment: Very interesting, but I'm not sure I like this line written on the website : The MultiPoint Mouse SDK does not support Windows Forms UI development.

Comment: The question seems to indicate a non-Windows platform.

Answer (score 1):

You can track multiple input devices separately using the `WM_INPUT` message.  Details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  However, this is Windows-specific, while you can access it from C# using p/invoke, your chances on Mono are slim to none.

On Linux, you probably would want to open and read from the various `/dev/input/`*`n`* devices and process multiple mice that way.  Or use the X-Windows input APIs.